# Data truncation: Data too long for column 'chain_of_ids' at row 1

Tags: mysql

MYSQL 8+ версии

Есть таблица для рекурсивного запроса `id`,`name`,`parentId`
Максимальный уровень вложенности 8
Искал в интернете как решить эту проблему - все говорят увеличить размерность поля существующей таблицы, но в моём запросе таблицы не существует на жестком диске. Ошибка в том что во втором выражении получается слишком длинная строка, НО! я пробовал

менять CONCAT(`id`,'') на CONCAT(`id`,'___________________________________________________')

И CONCAT(at.`chain_of_ids`,',',c.`id`) на CONCAT(at.`chain_of_ids`,',') - это работает без ошибки, хотя строка получается намного длинней чем ожидается от изначального запроса,

также я натыкаюсь на эту ошибку если менять CONCAT(at.`chain_of_ids`,',',c.`id`) на CONCAT(at.`chain_of_ids`,',_')

```
WITH RECURSIVE `accumulation_table` AS (
    SELECT `id`,`name`, CONCAT(`id`,'') AS `chain_of_ids` FROM `Category` WHERE `parentId` = 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT c.`id`,c.`name`, CONCAT(at.`chain_of_ids`,',',c.`id`) AS `chain_of_ids`
    FROM `Category` c
    JOIN `accumulation_table` at ON at.id=c.parentId
)
SELECT * FROM `accumulation_table` a
```

Comment: поле хранится в int? пробовали преобразовывать поле к varchar?

Comment: В первой части вместо concat попробуйте `cast(id as char(100))`

Comment: @Mike - это помогло - напишите пожалуйста для всех ответ почему так произошло. я пробовал вместо CONCAT(`id`,'') ставить пустую строку, даже строковый символ и все равно вызывало ошибку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В первой части запроса используйте явное указание типа и длины данных для поля. С помощью `cast(id as char(100))`. Если этого не сделать, то MySQL пытается понять используемый тип данных автоматически. Строковые функции на подобии `concat()` или строки фиксированной длины сообщают MySQL тип данных char с минимально возможной длиной. Т.е. для id=10 он выдаст после преобразования тип char(2). Во второй части запроса MySQL уже не меняет выбранный тип данных и пытается добавлять новые символы к короткой строке, что вызывает переполнение.